# jQuery get and set text using 1 or 2 attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows and columns, giving me lots of cells, in the `<TD>` i have a unique id, and an X Y value. like so

```
<td id='01-01-01-12345' x='6' y='8'> text/value here </td>
<td id='01-01-01-67890' x='6' y='9'> text/value here </td>
```

I want to be able get the text using either the ID or a combination of the x and y values. But im also wanting to be able to set the text also using either of the two options.

The reason for this is when i click on any cell, i can grab either of them values, and then using the x&y i can then get/change the neighbouring cells text also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is invalid HTML, at least you should use custom data attributes (`data-x`). And getting the “neighboring” cells would be possible without the id or using those x/y values as well, by going via the row and the position of the cell in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select using the id, simply use

```
var value = $('#01-01-01-12345').html();
```

To select using the attributes, use the attribute selector: `td[attribute=value]`. You can combine them as following:

```
var value = $('td[x="6"][y="8"]').html();
```

For the documentation about the selectors, see this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have your id stored in a variable called `id`. Then this

```
$("#" + id)
```

will yield the desired result. If you want to get an element by a combination of attributes, then, if we suppose that you have an object, containing key-value pairs defining the combination, you can do as follows:

```
var selector = "td";
for (var key in myObject) {
    selector += '[' + key + '="' + myObject[key] + '"]';
}
var myElements = $(selector);
```

If you have the result of a jquery call in a variable `element`, then:

- `element.html()` returns the inner html of the element
- `element.html(newValue)` modifies the inner html of the element
- `element.text()` returns the inner text of the element
- `element.text(newValue)` modifies the inner text of the element

Answer (score -1):

To get the text use this:-

```
var value = $('#01-01-01-12345').html();
```

to set the text use this:-

```
$('#01-01-01-12345').html('your text');
```